# Selecting the min value in a SQL result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, min

Using SQL Server 2012, I need to select the minimum date from a record set which is as follows.

```
personID    score
________    _____
 2            10
 2            15
 2            25
 3            73
 3            15
```

I would like my result set to be as follows

```
personID     score
________     _____
2              10
3              15
```

So essentially a single result set with the lowest score for each person. I have tried various forms of grouping and min and cannot seem to get it. I feel like this should be simple :(

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this:-

```
select personID, min(score) as Score from table group by personID
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I thought I had tried this! I will mark this the answer asap.